# 405 method not allowed while refreshing JWT Token - Django, Angular

Tags: python, django, angular, jwt

I'm using JWT Authentication in my Django/Angular project and weird thing happens when I'm trying to get a new access token when the old one expired.

I get a 405 POST METHOD NOT ALLOWED. I've set up corsheaders to allow all the methods and external hosts to access the app. 
The request looks fine as I'm sending the refresh token to get a new access token.

What I've noticed is that it happens only on the pages which are sending POST request to django to access some data before displaying it. 
When I'm on a page that sends GET request or nothing, obtaining new token works perfectly good.

Please take a look at the code and the responses.

**Error response**
[image: Error response]

**settings.py**

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
  '127.0.0.1:4200',
  '127.0.0.1:8082',
)

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
  'DELETE',
  'GET',
  'OPTIONS',
  'PATCH',
  'POST',
  'PUT',
]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
  'accept',
  'accept-encoding',
  'authorization',
  'content-type',
  'dnt',
  'origin',
  'user-agent',
  'x-csrftoken',
  'x-requested-with',
]
```

**Handling 401 error and getting a new token in angular**

```js
       private handle401Error(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler ) : Observable<any> {
        if(!this.isRefreshing) {
            this.isRefreshing = true;
            this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);

            return this.userService.refreshToken().pipe(
                switchMap((token:any) => {
                    this.isRefreshing = false;
                    this.refreshTokenSubject.next(token.access);

                    return next.handle(this.addToken(request, token.access));
                }));
        } else {
            return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
                filter(token => token != null),
                take(1),
                switchMap(access => {
                    return next.handle(this.addToken(request, access));
                })
            );
        }
    }


    refreshToken() {
        return this.http.post(`${this.apiUrl}/api/token/refresh`, {
          'refresh': this.getRefreshToken()
        }).pipe(tap((tokens: any) => {
          this.setJwtToken(tokens.access);
        }, err => {
          console.log(err);
        }));
      }
```

I've tried with corsheaders, I've tried to print all the data that is being sent and all the interceptors but I'm out of ideas.

Is there a chance those POST requests switch somehow and they go to wrong urls?

Comment: is `/api/token/refresh` suppose to be a post request ?

Comment: Yeah, the refresh token goes to /api/token/refresh and I'm supposed to receive access token instead

Comment: Make sure that your API is accepting a POST request,.